# Binding XamDataGrid to XmlDataProvider in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, infragistics, xamdatagrid, xmldataprovider

I'm unable to bind a `XamDataGrid` to an `XmlDataProvider` property in my MVVM styled project.

I'm getting an XML string from a WebService call, creating an XmlDataProvider and then trying to bind it to the XamDataGrid. The XmlDataProvider is getting initialized properly. It's just the binding part that's not going right.

#### View.xaml

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Source=provider, XPath=Row, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

#### ViewModel.cs

```
public XmlDataProvider provider { get; private set; }

private void method()
{
            string xmlString = webservice.runQuery();

            // prepare xml
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

            provider = new XmlDataProvider();

            if (provider != null)
            {
                provider.Document = doc;
                provider.XPath = "/Results";
            }
}
```

#### Sample xml string

```
<Results>
    <Row>
        <! -- my data -->
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <! -- my data -->
    </Row>
</Results>
```

I was able to do this without much difficulty in the code-behind way by following the sample Infragistics code. But, it's the MVVM way I'm having difficulty with.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740367/640378) doesn't seem to work for XamDataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataContext="{Binding provider}" DataSource="{Binding XPath=Row, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Also, I was originally missing the following:

```
private set
{
    _provider = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("provider");
}
```